# Trying to send messages after interaction with a emoji, using wait_for()

Tags: discord.py

Anybody that can see fast why this code won't work. So I want the myEmbed2 to be sent after they have interacted with the emoji. Also, I would like to have a myEmbed3 that's going to be after this again. Any feedback I would be grateful

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'test':
        channel = client.get_channel(XXXXXXXXXXXXX)

        myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="News Feed", 
            description="The #announcements will be your most important channel here! You'll be able to keep up to date with everything which is happening within the server so you'll never miss a beat!", 
            color=0x00ff00)
        myEmbed.add_field(name="It should only take a few minutes!", value="Press the button below to continue")
        myEmbed.set_footer(text="Christer - How does it work", icon_url="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2619/PNG/512/among_us_discord_icon_156922.png")

        myEmbed2 = discord.Embed(title="News Feed", 
            description="The #announcements will be your most important channel here! You'll be able to keep up to date with everything which is happening within the server so you'll never miss a beat!", 
            color=0x00ff00)
        myEmbed2.add_field(name="It should only take a few minutes!", value="Press the button below to continue")
        myEmbed2.set_footer(text="Christer - How does it work", icon_url="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2619/PNG/512/among_us_discord_icon_156922.png")       

        message = await channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
        await message.add_reaction("")
        await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check = lambda reaction, user: user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "")
        await channel.send(embed=myEmbed2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by won't work? And also, you should add a same-message check in the wait_for's check function.

Answer (score 1):

```py
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content == 'test':
            channel = client.get_channel(XXXXXXXXXXXXX)
    
            myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="News Feed", 
                description="The #announcements will be your most important channel here! You'll be able to keep up to date with everything wich is happening within the server so you'll never miss a beat!", 
                color=0x00ff00)
            myEmbed.add_field(name="It should only take a few minutes!", value="Press the button below to continue")
            myEmbed.set_footer(text="Christer - How does it work", icon_url="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2619/PNG/512/among_us_discord_icon_156922.png")      
    
            new_message = await channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
            await new_message.add_reaction("")
            await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check = lambda reaction, user: user == message.author and reaction.message == new_message and str(reaction.emoji) == "")
    
            await channel.send(embed=myEmbed)
```

Here, I added a check to the lambda. Also, you have the same embed twice so why set it in two different variables rather than using one? Then you store your expected message in a variable named message. Be careful, because you create a name conflict with the message parameter of your on_message function.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, really appreciate it! The thing is that I want two different messages sent as a sequence. Right now both are sending at the same time. See picture (https://imgur.com/a/QGl5z0J). Do you know how I could fix this? How would this be if I set myEmbed2 as a new variable?

Comment: In this case you can define a new message in a different variable as you had done (except that you had stored exactly the same message). And you put in exactly the same check as me? If so, there's no reason for it to happen like on your screen.